# R : object in custom function is not found for specific usage

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, ggpubr

I face a problem with R (and its well known rigor in dealing with objects...) : I wrote a custom function to plot dotplots from ggplots and add a custom p value with brackets. The problem is not the plot (it works well...) but dealing with objects and functions : I cannot use an object created inside the function. Some code to explain :

```r
pval.label <- function(p)
{
   if (p < 0.001) { return("p<0.001") }
   else { return(paste0("p = ", round(p, digits = 2))) }
}

dot_plot <- function(data, var, endpoint, title, ylab)
{
   endpoint = deparse(substitute(endpoint))
   var = deparse(substitute(var))
   df = data.frame(var = data[[var]], endpoint = data[[endpoint]])

   pvalue = compare_means(data = df, formula = var ~ endpoint)
   pvalue <- pvalue %>% mutate(y.position = 120*(max(df$var)/100))

   plot =
      ggplot(df, aes(x=endpoint, y=var)) +
      labs(title = title, y = ylab, x="") +
      geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', stackratio=1.7, binwidth = .8, show.legend = F,
                   aes(fill = endpoint, color = endpoint)) +
      stat_summary(fun=median, geom="crossbar", lwd=.5, width=.7, col="black", show.legend=F) +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#2d419b", "#ee2025")) +
      scale_color_manual(values=c("#2d419b", "#ee2025")) +
      theme_classic() +
      theme(text = element_text(family = "sans", face = "bold"),
            plot.title = element_text(size = 14, hjust = .5, lineheight = 1.5),
            axis.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", colour = "black"),
            axis.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold", colour = "black"),
            axis.line = element_line(size = 1),
            axis.ticks = element_line(size = 1), axis.ticks.length = unit(5, "pt")) +
      stat_pvalue_manual(pvalue, label = "{pval.label(pvalue$p)}", bracket.size = 1, size = 4)
   plot
}
```

The problem is with this line :
`stat_pvalue_manual(pvalue, label = "{pval.label(pvalue$p)}", bracket.size = 1, size = 4)`
It says the object "pvalue" is not found. But, if I create this object outside the function and have it in R environment, it works well !!

How to explain that ? And how to deal with it ?

Thanks,
Olivier

Comment: R usually does not store, into the global environment, variables created inside a function (you might want to read about scopes and environments in R). I think you might be looking for the function `assign` to save a variable inside a function, into the global environment.

Comment: If you want to use any values you created inside a function outside of that function, you need to `return()` them from the function. Maybe checkout this guide to R function: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/functions.html#return-values

Comment: Well, thank you for your answers but it is not the expected solution. I mean, I think assign a variable to the global environment will work, but why does it need to be in the global environment ? Is that a particular behavior of ggpubr::stat_pvalue_manual label ? My other variables in the function's environment work as expected...

Comment: Note that the problem with pvalue is not with its first occurrence in the given line, but with the second one between brackets ! (it is the reason why I declared the pval.label() function in the global environment).